# Left and right derivatives at a point

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a function wich is continuously differentiable on the real line except at $x=0$, where $f$ has a jump discontinuity (ie $\lim_{x\to 0^+ }f(x)\neq \lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)$). Also suppose that right and left hand side limit of $f'$ $$\lim_{x\to 0^+ }f'(x), \lim_{x\to 0^-}f'(x)$$ both exist. Is it possible that $$\lim_{x\to 0^+ }f'(x)= \lim_{x\to 0^-}f'(x)??$$
Any hint would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Suppose that $f$ is piecewise linear with a jump discontinuity at $0$, where the slope of $f$ is the same to the left and to the right of $0$.